# Process.PrivateMemorySize64 returning committed memory instead of private

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a program in C# using .NET 4.5, that will allow me to monitor the memory, CPU and network usage of a particular process, and then chart that data according to my needs.

In order to obtain the memory usage for a particular process, I am checking the [`PrivateMemorySize64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.privatememorysize64.aspx) property for that `Process` object. I am expecting to see the Private memory used by that process, but instead, it is showing the amount in Commit, as confirmed by the Windows Resource Monitor.

My questions are:

1) Does anybody know why this error is happening?
2) Is there a fix for it?
3) If no fix, is there another straightforward way I can obtain the private memory reserved for a process?

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
using System;

// I add all the open Processes to an array
Process[] localAll = Process.GetProcesses();

// I then add all the processes to a combobox to select from
// There's a button that updates labels with requested info

Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
label1.Text = p[0].PrivateMemorySize64.ToString() + " bytes";
```

Comment: once again..hard to tell what's wrong when we can't see the code that you are currently working with.. it would surely help to show your code

Comment: From reading the documentation for `PrivateMemorySize64`, the commit size is exactly what I would expect it to return. What, exactly, do you mean by "private memory"? Are you talking about the *private working set*?

Comment: Yes, I do mean the private working set. I apologize for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment you said you are looking for private working set. It appears from this link [How to calculate private working set (memory)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611141/calculate-private-working-set-memory-using-c-sharp)
that it is indeed not a part of the Process class. You must instead use a performance counter.

Copied and pasted from the other answer just in case for some reason it gets deleted.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string prcName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
        var counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", prcName);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}K", counter.RawValue / 1024);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that while `Process.PrivateMemorySize64` access is practically instant, creating a performance counter takes considerable time (seconds) and may not be acceptable in the applications that require high performance or real time reporting. As `Process` and `PerformanceCounter` are the descendants of `IDisposable`, you also have to wrap in `using`.