# How can i get the RAM usage of my process just like in Task Manager?

Tags: c#

I'm making a program on C# language, and one of my task it's write to the log file used RAM of the process of my program. 
I used `WorkingSet64` as someone advised me, but it showing so very different value from what is at the Task Manager.
How can i get the exact value as it showing in Task Manager ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755162/process-privatememorysize64-returning-committed-memory-instead-of-private

Comment: Note that TaskManager shows a simplified single view of memory, not really the calibration point here.

Answer (score 4):

Getting the process

```
Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
```

To get the private memory usage.

```
proc.PrivateMemorySize64;
```

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s80a75e5(VS.80).aspx) might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you work on **Visual Studio 2015**, you can use the `Performances profiler`

In the `debug` menu select:

- Debug

  - Profiler

    - Performances Profiler

Then select `.Net memory allocation`

[image]