# How to get application memory usage as shown in Task Manager?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, process, ram

I am trying to get the memory usage of my application but for some reason i am getting different size than in task manager

I am using:

[image]

Task manager shows that my application occupies 45mb , while when i pulling it in my code i get 85mb
how can i get the same size as in task manager (without using wmi)

Comment: Add `process.Refresh()` before you call `process.PrivateMemorySize64`

Comment: did not helped, getting the same values as before

Comment: If you are into such things I heavily recommend to drop Task Manager and replace it with Process Explorer from Sysinternals. See this video http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-2-Process-Explorer

Comment: i am using Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: i added a screenshot of the code and what's happening

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably you're looking at the wrong column in "Task manager" or using the wrong property in Process class..

I guess you're looking for `WorkingSet64` not `PrivateMemorySize64`. `PrivateMemorySize64` is the amount of virtual memory allocated for the process, not the physical memory. For physical memory use `WorkingSet64`.

Also, you need to call `process.Refresh()` before accessing any of the dynamic properties in process class as it is heavily cached.

```
process.Refresh();
_data.MemoryUsed = (process.WorkingSet64).ConvertBytesToMegabytes().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: i added refresh and uploaded the code while debugging as you see the memory size is different, also there are not drastic changes in memory size it's pretty stable at 45-47mb~

Comment: Don't check the process memory while debugging. Run the process out of the debugger and check. Because when debugging visual studio will run hosting process for you *YourProcess.vshost.exe*. That can cause confusion. I tested this with printing the output in console (running out of visual studio) and that worked perfectly. Also change that `Sleep(200)` to `Sleep(1000)` so that it will sync with task manager.

Comment: I am trying without visual studio and debug and it is still not right, i don't see the vshost in task manager also

Comment: As I said, you're still looking at the wrong column in the task manager. You need to check the "Working set" column. If you need private working set check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611141/calculate-private-working-set-memory-using-c-sharp)

Comment: also WorkingSet64 shows 114mb, PrivateMemorySize64 shows 80-84mb

Comment: is there a way to get it from Process without using Performence counters or wmi?

Comment: @atikot Sorry, I don't know alternate way. What's wrong with performance counter anyway?

Comment: @atikot You could also go directly to the WinAPI and [P/Invoke GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/psapi.getprocessmemoryinfo)

Comment: Does this work across operating systems: Windows, Linux, MacOS?

Answer (score 10):

None of the above is working for me. I have therefore found this solution

> [How to get application memory usage as shown in Task Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720684/how-to-get-application-memory-usage-as-shown-in-task-manager)

by Hans Passant which is doing a great job.

```
string prcName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
var counter_Exec = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", prcName);
double dWsp_Exec =  (double)counter_Exec.RawValue / 1024.0; <---that is the value in KB
```

Also, I sometimesfound a minor different (<10%) which could be related to a different update.
[image]

The only minor drawback is that the first instruction take a long time (5") for accumulating data so it might be handled in a thread.

Answer (score 3):

Try once with the following code,may be it will help

```
PerformanceCounter PC = new PerformanceCounter();
PC.CategoryName = "ServerProcess";
PC.CounterName = "Working Set - Private";
PC.InstanceName = JSP[0].ProcessName; //Process
RAM_memorysize = PC.NextValue();            //float RAM_memorysize;
PC.Close();
PC.Dispose();
```