# C# Why my performance monitoring value is not exactly same value in Task Manager?

Tags: c#, performance

I follow the accepted answer [Using PerformanceCounter to Track Memory and CPU Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411805/using-performancecounter-to-track-memory-and-cpu-usage-per-process)

but I've found that the result is not same value in Task Manager:

[image]

```
var processName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
PerformanceCounter ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set", processName);
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", processName);
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    double ram = ramCounter.NextValue();
    double cpu = cpuCounter.NextValue();
    Console.WriteLine("RAM: " + (ram / 1024 / 1024) + " MB; CPU: " + (cpu) + " %");
 }
```

Is the code correct? How can I get the exactly same value in Task Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is about to be good but need little improvements:

1. `"Process"-"% Processor Time"` is always return CPU usage across all CPUs in the system. So returning value should be devided by `Environment.ProcessorCount`. Thats the actual value the Task Manager displays
2. As Hans Passant said in this answer [How to calculate private working set (memory)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611141/how-to-calculate-private-working-set-memory/2611248#2611248) 
   Task Manager actually use `"Process", "Working Set - Private"` but not
   `"Process"-"Working Set"`

Final code:

```
        var processName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
        PerformanceCounter ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", processName);
        PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", processName);

        while (true)
        {
            double ram = ramCounter.NextValue();
            double cpu = cpuCounter.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount;

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("RAM: "
                              + (ram / 1024).ToString("N0") + " KB; CPU: "
                              + cpu.ToString("N1") + " %;");

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Anton!